# Save Images to Sd Card in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sdcard

I can save only 1 image, this codes saving the last taken image with the same name so old images are deleting automaticly. I should save lots of image to sd card, what should I do for fix this code?

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == IMAGE_ACTION_CODE) {
        // 2
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imagev.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        // 3
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        // 4

        String filename;
        Date date = new Date(0);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        filename =  sdf.format(date);
        File file = new    

        File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+filename+".jpg");

        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
            // 5
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

i tried this code but still taking error in logcat  :

```
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); filename = sdf.format(new Date());
```

I realize this problem is not about date format .

Still taking error in logcat for example :

```
  12-20 08:48:32.120: E/SoundPool(288): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Lock.ogg
12-20 08:48:32.120: E/SoundPool(288): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Unlock.ogg
12-20 08:48:32.620: E/EventHub(288): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
12-20 08:48:32.620: E/EventHub(288): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
12-20 08:48:32.720: E/Trace(288): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-20 08:48:33.800: E/CommandListener(34): Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlan0/disable_ipv6: No such file or directory
12-20 08:48:33.840: E/WifiStateMachine(288): Failed to disable IPv6: java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '1 interface ipv6 wlan0 disable' failed with '400 1 Failed to change IPv6 state (No such file or directory)'
12-20 08:48:33.920: E/MobileDataStateTracker(288): default: Ignoring feature request because could not acquire PhoneService
12-20 08:48:33.920: E/MobileDataStateTracker(288): default: Could not enable APN type "default"
12-20 08:48:36.850: E/Trace(349): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-20 08:48:38.330: D/dalvikvm(288): GC_CONCURRENT freed 273K, 9% free 4588K/5012K, paused 8ms+31ms, total 516ms
12-20 08:48:38.330: D/dalvikvm(288): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 284ms
12-20 08:48:38.340: D/dalvikvm(288): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 335ms
12-20 08:48:38.350: D/dalvikvm(288): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 317ms
12-20 08:48:38.350: I/ActivityManager(288): Start proc com.android.inputmethod.latin for service com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME: pid=377 uid=10018 gids={50018}
12-20 08:48:38.360: D/dalvikvm(288): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 254ms
12-20 08:48:38.590: E/Trace(377): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-20 08:48:39.500: E/ThrottleService(288): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-20 08:48:40.261: E/Trace(394): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-20 08:48:42.171: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
12-20 08:48:42.331: E/ActivityThread(377): Failed to find provider info for com.android.inputmethod.latin.dictionarypack
12-20 08:48:42.502: E/BinaryDictionaryGetter(377): Could not find a dictionary pack
12-20 08:48:43.362: I/ActivityManager(288): Start proc android.process.acore for content provider com.android.providers.userdictionary/.UserDictionaryProvider: pid=432 uid=10010 gids={50010, 3003, 1015, 1028}
12-20 08:48:43.471: E/StrictMode(377): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
12-20 08:48:43.471: E/StrictMode(377): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
12-20 08:48:43.471: E/StrictMode(377):  at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
12-20 08:48:43.471: E/StrictMode(377):  at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:412)
12-20 08:48:43.471: E/StrictMode(377):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetFdNative(Native Method)
12-20 08:48:43.471: E/StrictMode(377):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetFd(AssetManager.java:428)
```

AND taking this error in error log :

**Warning:the environment variable home is not set . The following directory will be used to store the Git .
Warning:Unhandled event loop exception.

Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in**

Comment: Your images are saved like: "20131220000000"? There is no difference in HHmmss?

Comment: saving with 1970010102000121.jpg name . Yes .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `SimpleDateFormat` is underline in yellow. You see this Lint:

> To get local formatting use getDateInstance(), getDateTimeInstance(), or getTimeInstance(), or use new SimpleDateFormat(String template, Locale locale) with for example Locale.US for ASCII dates.

It means, you missed an argument to have the correct time.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17808060/2668136), and try the code below:

```
String filename;
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyyMMddHHmmss", java.util.Locale.getDefault());
filename =  sdf.format(date);
```

Or use `Locale.UK` instead of `java.util.Locale.getDefault()`, or something in the list here: [Locale Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#default_locale).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Fllo , this code fixed my first problem but still taking error about another things .

Answer (score 0):

```
Date date = new Date(0);
```

This creates a `Date` object which is 0 milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.

You probably want

```
Date date = new Date();
```

which creates a `Date` object with the current date and time.

---

The exception in logcat `java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called` is because for some resason you haven't closed a file you opened. At least you should change

```
try {
    file.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
    // 5
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
    fo.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

to something like

```
FileOutputStream fo = null;
try {
    file.createNewFile();
    fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
    // 5
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (fo != null) {
        try { fo.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {}
    }
}
```

so the `FileOutputStream` is closed regardless of any exceptions.

Comment: when i use => Date date = new Date();
Date is underlining with red color . And giving error : _The constructor Date() is undefined_

Comment: @gk91 Make sure you're importing `java.util.Date` and not e.g. `java.sql.Date`